# In CUDA9, is "cudaMemcpyAsync()" both a device and a host function?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

According to the [official CUDA doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g85073372f776b4c4d5f89f7124b7bf79), we have

```
__host__ ​ __device__ ​cudaError_t cudaMemcpyAsync ( void* dst, const void* src, size_t count, cudaMemcpyKind kind, cudaStream_t stream = 0 )
```

which implies it is both a host and a device function.  However, in the actual installation on my local Linux box, I am seeing in `/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h`:

```
/** CUDA Runtime API Version */
#define CUDART_VERSION  9000
// Many lines away...
extern __host__ __cudart_builtin__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaMemcpyAsync(void *dst, const void *src, size_t count, enum cudaMemcpyKind kind, cudaStream_t stream __dv(0));
```

which seems to imply it is strictly a host function.

I tried to compile a simple kernel that calls `cudaMemcpyAsync()`, and got the error

> streaming.cu(338): error: calling a __host__
>   function("cudaMemcpyAsync") from a __global__
>   function("loopy_plus_one") is not allowed

which is another piece of evidence.

So I'm really confused: is the doc incorrect, or is my CUDA installation out of date?

EDIT: update - if I change my compilation command to explicitly specify sm_60, i.e., `nvcc -arch=sm_60 -o out ./src.cu`, then the compilation error is gone, but a new one pops out:

> ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'cudaMemcpyAsync'

Comment: any time you are attempting to use the device runtime, you should link against `-lcudadevrt` in your `sm_60` case are you linking with that?  In the programming guide, `cudaMemcpyAsync` is part of the device runtime (see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference) ) which should be available if you are compiling for a compute capability of 3.5 or higher, and linking against the device runtime, and using `-rdc=true`

Answer (score 3):

There is a device implementation of `cudaMemcpyAsync` in the CUDA *device* runtime API, which you can see documented in the Programming Guide [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference). There, within the introductory section on Dynamic Parallelism it [notes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#overview)

> Dynamic Parallelism is only supported by devices of compute capability
>   3.5 and higher

and within the documentation it also notes usage of the device runtime API memory functions:

> Notes about all memcpy/memset functions:
>
> - Only async memcpy/set functions are supported
> - Only device-to-device memcpy is permitted
> - May not pass in local or shared memory pointers

You can also find exact [instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compiling-and-linking) for how you must compile and link code which uses the device runtime API:

> CUDA programs are automatically linked with the host runtime library
>   when compiled with nvcc, but the device runtime is shipped as a static
>   library which must explicitly be linked with a program which wishes to
>   use it.
>
> The device runtime is offered as a static library (cudadevrt.lib on
>   Windows, libcudadevrt.a under Linux and MacOS), against which a GPU
>   application that uses the device runtime must be linked. Linking of
>   device libraries can be accomplished through nvcc and/or nvlink.

So to make this work you must do exactly three things:

1. Choose a *physical* target  architecture which is at least compute capability 3.5 when you are compiling
2. Use separate compilation for device code when you are compiling
3. Link the CUDA device runtime library

It is for these three reasons (i.e. not doing any of them) that you have seen the compilation and linking errors when trying to use `cudaMemcpyAsync` inside kernel code.

Answer (score -3):

It seems to work once I specify the compute capability correctly,

```
nvcc -arch=compute_60 -o out src.cu
```

Comment: Does this override driver API options? (for example, just like you wrote, selected 60 but in driver api runtime compilation, picked 30 and run it on Kepler)

Comment: because that option generates only ptx and does not run the code through ptxas